# How to make a check box editable

Tags: xpages, javabeans

Domino 8.5.3 FP5, Designer  9.0.1.

I have an empty xpage containing only the following checkbox. I am not able to make it editable. It show the right value, but appear as disabled.

```
        <xp:checkBox text="Label" id="checkBox1" uncheckedValue="true" 
        checkedValue="false" 
        value="#{javascript:jBeanConfigSupport.validationEnabledTxt}">
        </xp:checkBox>
```

If I remove the binding to Java bean, all run fine. This is the Java bean code (part)

```
private boolean isValidationEnabled=true;

    public String getValidationEnabledTxt() {
        return String.valueOf(isValidationEnabled);
    }

    public void setValidationEnabledTxt(String onOff) {
        isValidationEnabled=Boolean.parseBoolean(onOff);
    }
    public void setValidationEnabledTxt(boolean onOff) {
        isValidationEnabled=onOff;
    }
```

Where Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're binding using SSJS, so instead of binding to the `validationEnabledTxt` property of your bean, the result of `jBeanConfigSupport.validationEnabledTxt` is being used to determine what it should be bound to. `value="#{jBeanConfigSupport.validationEnabledTxt}"` should work to map to the getter and setter.

Comment: Thank Paul. It works putting as Expression Language. Thank you very much indeed, and thank to @steve for clarify. No way using SSJS?

Comment: If you want to bind to the property of your bean, you need to use Expression Language. SSJS is just a String, computed at runtime or page load to return a value. You don't want to bind to the result of the SSJS, so SSJS is the wrong approach. If it was a dominoDocument instead of a bean, SSJS would be binding to the value of a field rather than a field itself. It's similar to trying to run SSJS in CSJS - the SSJS is computed by the server and the result used by the CSJS, the SSJS itself is not used "within" the CSJS.

Answer (score 1):

Francesco,

You need to have a working setter method for this to be editable.  In your case there is probably a problem with the setValidationEnabledTxt() method that is causing the field in the UI to be readonly.

Try adding "this" to your code so that it reads this.isValidationEnables = Boolean.parseBoolean(onOff);

Comment: Please try using Expression Language to bind to the bean as Paul suggests and then update whether that fixes it or not.  If that doesn't work, then try changing the type of the field from boolean to String, and then backtrack from there. (boolean *should* be just fine)